# How do I find out version of currently running Solr?

Tags: solr

Please tell me how can I determine the version number of currently running solr ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

On the **Solr Admin** page click on **[INFO]**.  The next screen will have the version.

(For me, the Solr admin page is located here: http://{host-name-or-ip}:{port}/solr/admin, I found I was dealing with an older version.  Solr Specification Version: 1.4.0   Solr Implementation Version: 1.4.0 833479)

[image: info in Solr Admin]

Comment: Is there a way to get this if you do not have Admin access to the index?  As in if hosted by a 3rd party provider?

Answer (score 52):

With a HTTP GET request to:

```
yoursolrhost:8983/solr/admin/info/system
```

you'll retrieve a structure in many different representations (xml, json, php, python,...).

the `lucene` key of the structure contains version numbers.

For example, using json output:

```
http://yoursolrhost:8983/solr/admin/info/system?wt=json
```

The `lucene` key looks like this:

```
"lucene": {
    "solr-spec-version": "4.6.0",
    "solr-impl-version": "4.6.0 1543363 - simon - 2013-11-19 11:16:33",
    "lucene-spec-version": "4.6.0",
    "lucene-impl-version": "4.6.0 1543363 - simon - 2013-11-19 11:05:50"
},
```

Comment: oddly i get null for all of these

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites It isnt visible for me either, neither is it showing up on the UI.. how did you check the solr version?

Comment: @Zac Thanks solr was not accessible in the browser - you saved my day

Answer (score 14):

solr admin "infos" button links to "admin/registry.jsp"

so you can get the version with :

wget -O- "http://solr_ip_adress.lan:8080/solr/admin/registry.jsp" | grep 'solr-spec-version'

Answer (score 11):

You could use `http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/info/system?wt=json` to gather the details and Solr version too.

Tested on Solr v6.6.0

Answer (score 5):

You need to query Solr using the SystemInfoHandler:

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/handler/admin/SystemInfoHandler.html

Comment: When clicked info on admin page i got
 Solr Specification Version: 1.4.0.2009.11.19.08.31.18
Solr Implementation Version: 1.5-dev 882138 - grantingersoll - 2009-11-19 08:31:18
 so is it 1.5-dev that am using.

Comment: @kshama: yes, it's 1.5 svn revision 882138

Comment: Can you provide an example query in your answer?  I am quite new to Solr.  Thanks.

Comment: @Brad: I wish I could.. this answer is about 2 years old and I don't even remember answering :)

Answer (score 5):

You can simply go to your Solr Dashboard page as in URL

```
http://localhost:8983/solr
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumption, you use version 3.6, port 8080. Go to
http://localhost:8080/solr/default/admin/registry.jsp

You will see result:

```
Solr Implementation Version: 3.6.0 1310449 - rmuir - 2012-04-06 11:34:07
```

Answer (score 0):

From the command line of a Linux server running solr:

```
sudo service solr status
```

Depending on your version of Linux, I imagine you might have to modify that to use `systemctl` instead of `service`, or other means of calling the solr service.

Comment: Since I return to this SO result each time I have to look up how to do this again, I figure this answer is needed.